# Key Store Password Lost

Tags: android, passwords, keystore, publishing

I lost my password of Keystore file. I have already published my application and have few users who use that app. Now I am unable to publish its newer version. I will publish that app using different keystore file but before that I want to notify all that users to update their application to new one. How can I do that?

Comment: You can only add description in current app in `play store` about new app. Also if you've registration option in current app then drop mail to all users.

Comment: try this link https://code.google.com/p/android-keystore-password-recover/wiki/HowTo

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to recover your key.
If you deleted from your computer then recover your computer files.
and if you lost your file in another platform(any where) ! try to recover because Once again,there is no way to recover this.

The only option I see here is to unpublish your app , change your package name and republish it . But take into consideration you will loose your current users.
and try to email all your existing users for your new publish.

Comment: Thanks Very much @Kunwar Avanish